# Improve Efficiency of Ruby Model Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, where-clause

### Problem:

In my customer model, I want to sum up all transactions where each payments' status is successful and either the `customer_id` matches the id of the current instance or the current instance's `parent_id`.  First, I was unable to get this to work at all because I was trying to do it all in one query.  Now I have what I'm looking for, but I'm afraid I'm not being nearly as efficient as I could be.

### Context:

- The transactions table has a `customer_id` column
- the customers table has a `parent_id` column.
- Customer class `has_many :transactions`
- Transactions class `belongs_to :customer`
- Transactions class `has_many :payments`

Here are my models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :transaction
end
```

### Question:

If this is the model property I'm using currently, how can I improve its performance, if at all?

```
def total_spent
  if customer_type == 1 # "child" customer
    Transaction.joins(:payments).where('payments.status' => 3).sum(:amount, :conditions => ['customer_id = ?', id])
  elsif customer_type == 2 # "parent" customer
    temp_transactions = Transaction.joins(:payments).where('payments.status' => 3)
    temp = temp_transactions.sum(:amount, :conditions => ['customer_id = ?', id])
    Customer.find_all_by_parent_group_id(id).each do |c|
      temp = temp + temp_transactions.sum(:amount, :conditions => ['customer_id = ?', c.id])
    end
    temp
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Transaction.joins(:payments)
   .joins(:customer)
   .where(:payments => {:status => 3})
   .where("customers.id = ? or customers.parent_id = ?", 5, 5)
   .sum(:amount)


SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_id 
FROM "transactions" 
    INNER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."transaction_id" = "transactions"."id" 
    INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."id" = "transactions"."customer_id" 
WHERE 
   "payments"."status" = 3 
   AND (customers.id = 5 or customers.parent_id = 5)
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I was afraid I wasn't going to be able to do this without adding a parent_id column to transactions table.  Being as new as I am to querying in general, did going from what I have to what you suggested significantly improve performance?

Comment: If performance isn't what you want, make sure you are indexing status and all the foreign keys.

Comment: I queried against an empty database, so I can't answer the question about performance exactly.

Comment: I think the performance improvement largely depends on how many customers end up being children of the instance of Customer.  Before I had the temp_transactions, I was doing the `Transaction.joins(:payments).where('payments.status' => 3)` inside the each loop.  But it is nice to not have to `.sum(:amount, :conditions => ['customer_id = ?', c.id])` each iteration.  Thanks again :)  I'm going to look up indexing now to see what that will do for me.